# CakePHP - Miles Uploader Plugin - Isset Error

Tags: cakephp, plugins, uploader

I have tried several CakePHP file uploaders, but have not been successful' in setting up and making it work. I've settled down with [Miles Uploader Plugin](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader) and I am doing everything I can to make it work. Installation instructions are excellent and I have followed them to the letter, but I still cant get it to work.

When I post an Article I get the following error:

```
 Warning (2): Illegal offset type in isset or empty [APP/plugins/uploader/controllers/components/uploader.php, line 1104]
    }
    if (isset($this->_data[$file])) {
```

I am making the following call in my add articles view

```
...
echo $form->input('main_image', array('type' => 'file'));
...
```

And I am using the following in my add action but it is returning false

```
...
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    //This call is not successful which skips to the }else{ display the message below
    if ($data = $this->Uploader->upload('main_image')) {
        // Upload successful, do whatever
    }else{
            $this->setFlash('Uploader Error',true);
    }
}
...
```

Can anyone please shed some light on what could possibly be wrong.

---

** EDIT **

---

**I am not able to try this out right now, but do I need to do the following to make it work:**

```
if ($data = $this->Uploader->upload(data['Article']['main_image'])) {
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent many hours trying to figure out why it does not work. Finally I gave up last night trying and settled with trying to configure CakePHP's Media Plugin. That now works great. Setup was a breeze.